# Can the differential $\text{d}x$ be interpreted as a basis vector?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I want to add the numbers $1,2,$ and $3$ together. Visually, this can be done as

[image]

I can also use $1$ as a basis vector to add these numbers together:

[image]

Which translates to:
$$
1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 3 = 6
$$
Now consider the function $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Can the integral
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \ \text{d}x
$$
be interpreted in a similar way to the addition of the numbers $1,2,$ and $3$ above? More precisely, if the differential $\text{d}x$ can visually be interpreted as a point:

[image]

and if $f(x) \ \text{d}x$ can be visually interpreted as the scaling of this point to form a line:

[image]

Then couldn't the integral
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \ \text{d}x
$$
be interpreted as the length of the line formed by the concatenation of several smaller lines, each with a length of $f(x)$, and with $\text{d}x$ as a "basis vector", as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that's what the [theory of differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) does.

Comment: @Raskolnikov any specific part I should look into?

Comment: Any introduction to the subject would be enough to get the flavour of the topic. After that, it depends what you want to do with it.

Comment: It’s an amusing analogy but none of this is precise. Most glaringly, an integral is not a sum: it is the *limit* of a sum. Your “concatenation of several smaller lines” is at best an *approximation* of the integral, not equal to it. The space of differential 1-forms does indeed form a vector space, but this isn’t directly related to what you’re saying here.

Comment: @symplectomorphic if $$\int_a^b f(x) \ \text{d}x = \lim_{||\Delta x_i|| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \Delta x_i$$ then wouldn't my "concatenation" approximation get closer to the true integral as the consecutive points $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ (e.g. $x_0$ and $x_1$ in the last diagram) get closer to each other? I was implicitly assuming here that $||x_{i+1} - x_i|| \approx 0$.

Comment: I mean $||x_{i+1} - x_{i}|| = \text{d}x \ \forall i \in \{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Yes. But your post says you “interpret” the integral “as the length of the line formed by the concatenation of several smaller lines.” This is not correct. The integral is not (in general) equal to any one of those lengths, especially if your $dx$ is constant throughout the partition; the integral is rather the *limit* of those lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, that some such analogy has substance.

But/and an even better analogy, in anticipation of taking a limit (or, equivalently, thinking in terms of some sort of either heuristic or legitimate (Robinson, Nelson, et al) infinitesimals), would be to *stack* the lines of length $f(x_i)$ and width $dx$, to make a 2D *area*, rather than a long line of ever-increasing length while ever-diminishing width. This 2D picture would stabilize, in the sense of "coming into sharper focus" as the size of $dx$ went to $0$. The 1D model of the thing would get infinitely long and infinitesimally thin as $dx$ went to $0$, which (unless we are doing this in a nicely controlled environment for non-standard analysis) would blow up in our faces.

And, yes, this is a version of the "Riemann-sum" definition/characterization of "integral". In some form dating back to Archimedes and beyond, as I understand the history.